# Php OOP using the case method

Tags: php, oop, getter-setter

I'm a little confused with this OOP concept. I'm trying to set a value for a varable below;.

ie:

```
protected  $isAdmin;
```

I want to use a setter and getter to set this values; and use a caseMethod to set the values for the setter.

It might be easier to show you below;

```
 protected  $isAdmin = null;  

    public function isAdminWorker()
    {
        //this will get the preset values for the user; i.e admin worker or visitor.
        $theRole = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->getIdentity()->getRole();

    switch($theRole)
    {               
            case 'admin':

              $this->setIsAdmin($theRole);

        break;

            case 'visitor':
               $this->setVisitor($theRole);
        break;
        }    
    }

public function setIsAdmin($isAdmin)
    {
         $this->isAdmin = $isAdmin;
    } 

    public function getIsAdmin()
    {

        return $this->isAdmin;
    }
```

When I called the `$this->getIsAdmin()` it always returned a `NULL` value. So, the Case method is basically not setting the correct values.

I'm obviouly confused about setting values using the getter and setter method and would appriciate some advice on where I have gone wrong.

Comment: OK, so the method is probably not setting the correct value. See what's the value of `$this->isAdmin` before and after. Check the value of `$theRole`. This is basic debugging, I 'm not sure what kind of help you expect here.

Comment: Like already said, check the value of `$theRole`. Probably your method `$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->getIdentity()->getRole()` isn't returning "admin" or "visitor".

Comment: hi jon and kinkee. i have done all the basic debugging. the values prior to being set was null and the values after the setting was null. i am indeed a bit miffed about this one. bascially. it looks like my setter and getter method is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm obviouly confused about setting values using the getter and setter method and would appriciate some advice on where I have gone wrong

`isFoo()` or `hasFoo()` ("is" or "has" methods) are normally used to signify a `boolean` result.

I think if you are combining the `is` and `get` methods together it would lead to confusion.

Try to encapsulate the methods so they perform one task; a possible solution might be.

```
class MyClass {

  protected $identity;

  protected $role;

  public function getIdentity()
  {
    if (null == $this->identity) {
      $this->identity = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->getIdentity();
    }
    return $this->identity;
  }

  public function getRole()
  {
    if (null == $this->role) {
      $this->role = $this->getIdentity()->getRole();
    }
    return $this->role;
  }

  public function isAdmin()
  {
    return ('admin' === $this->getRole());
  }

  public function isVisitor()
  {
    return ('visitor' === $this->getRole());
  }

}
```

This gives you a clearer API and no need to "set" any roles etc

Comment: hello AlexP thank you for your recommendation; i will try it now. warm regards Andreea